# How to write values to an required column in excel file using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I have to write around 15000 rows to the specified column in an excel file using Open XML. I am new to this so plz help. I am facing difficulties in specifying the column where I want to add values to the excel. I have found some code to write to excel but how to choose a specified column.

```
static Cell AddCellWithText(string text) 
{ 
    Cell c1 = new Cell(); 
    c1.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;

    InlineString inlineString = new InlineString(); 
    Text t = new Text(); 
    t.Text = text; 
    inlineString.AppendChild(t);

    c1.AppendChild(inlineString);

    return c1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself, but looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc802319(v=office.14)#remarks) suggests the following should work.

```
static Cell AddCellWithText(string text) 
{ 
    Cell c1 = new Cell();
    c1.CellReference = "B2"; //The required position of cell in excel grid
    c1.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;

    InlineString inlineString = new InlineString(); 
    Text t = new Text(); 
    t.Text = text; 
    inlineString.AppendChild(t);

    c1.AppendChild(inlineString);

    return c1; 
}
```

For the above to work, `row.RowIndex` must match the corresponding row given in `cell.CellReference`. What I mean is if RowIndex = 1 then you can set CellReference to A1, B1, C1, etc. and for RowIndex = 2 CellReference must be A2, B2, C2, etc.

Comment: Hi Brother tried with this but still i didn't get. I have this link here can u try to help me with this to choose particular column to write. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2016/03/13/open-xml-create-excel-from-scratch/

Comment: Ok, I must mention that your `row.RowIndex` must match the corresponding row given in `cell.CellReference`. What I mean is if RowIndex = 1 then you can set CellReference to A1, B1, C1, etc. and for RowIndex = 2 CellReference must be A2, B2, C2, etc. Hope this helps.